# Google Sheets Function to determine when a referenced document was last altered

Tags: google-sheets, task-tracking

Context:
I have a Google Sheets document with my daily tasks in it.  Many of my tasks involve me checking to see if changes have been made to other Google Sheets (referenced in my daily task document) in the past day.

Goal:
I want a function which will tell me when one of the referenced Google sheets was last altered.

Here is an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JV-ZvO1P5PPU2Eoi7qSIKaeBWgHkmAA0BLEh8OmLCGI/edit?usp=sharing

I want the function to be in the B column.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple but will take a bit of code. You can go to Tools> Script Editor and create a function like such:

```
function timestamp() {
  return new Date()
}
```

You can then use that function in an If statement like the following:

```
IF(A2="","",timestamp(A2))
```

If the cell is blank the function will return blank, but when the cell is updated it will timestamp the change in that cell.

If you are unfamiliar with Apps Script you can learn how it works [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).